# In VS 2015, I get an IOException error only when debugging

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting an error during debugging, but not when I run without debugging.

```
IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\myproj\wwwroot\states.xml' because it is being used by another process.

Error Line: File.Create(filePath)
```

This is the code that it occurs on (note: this is being called from an async method from my MVC Core Controller):

```
public void SaveListAsXml(IList<T> list, string filePath)
        {
            var xmlString = ListToXML(list);
            var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

            using (var stream = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
                {
                    doc.Save(writer);
                }
            }
        }
```

These errors are usually thrown when you're trying to access something already has a handle open on it, but in this case, I can restart the PC and have this error the first time I run it with debugging attached.  One clue, is that I have noticed I sometimes have to 'step through' in the debugger twice on each line (due to the async parent method?).  This feels like a VS bug, but this is my first time using MVC Core so probably my misunderstanding.

Are the two things linked? (i.e. the repeated steps and the locked file?)

To confirm, this runs fine when I use CTRL+F5 (run without debugging).  The file is created and then read back with no problem.

When I run with debugging, it always throws this error, even if I delete the file before running it.  Do I need to explicitly close the file handle?

Comment: The build project has a bin/debug and bin/release folder.  Compare the dates of the two executables and see if they are the same.  You have to build both debug and release seperately otherwise the both executables don't get updated.

Comment: Anti-malware is always very interested in XML files.  Tends to go wrong right after they got copied when you built your program.  And won't go wrong when you press Ctrl+F5 because you didn't build.  Make an exclusion.

Comment: If you are stepping twice for each line that usually indicates you have multiple threads running, one debug step for each thread.  Take a closer look to see if you have duplicate calls somewhere or are calling the URL twice in succession.